# OpenShift app showing default page

Tags: java, git, openshift

I'm developing a small `Java` web app on `Glassfish 4`.

Since I need to use it for some time, I need it online so I went for `OpenShift`.

I have set up `rhc` and I have cloned my git repo successfully, but it still shows default page. http://professionalorientation-puskice.rhcloud.com/

This is `jBoss 7`, so, should I maybe use `Tomcat` instead? I don't see `Glassfish 4` offered.

Thanks for any heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Glassfish4 quickstart available here https://github.com/shekhargulati/glassfish4-openshift-quickstart